# EMR erorr 'Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: amazon-emr

getting error in AWS EMR not sure why it's trying to connect to Mysql DB. I don't have any code that connects to mysql.

Error:
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!

Comment: this sounds strange. Do you have a code/service which internally is trying to get data from MySQL?

Comment: No, we don’t even use MySql in our project.

Comment: What do you mean local? on the EMR?

Comment: It’s the error message on EMR cluster logs, I don’t mean anything.